# How to edit this mySQL query to not select rows that have same value in 2 columns?

Tags: mysql

Running the following query I get the following message

**invalid use of group by**

```
SELECT COUNT( id ) AS pages,
       hash, MIN( DATE( TIMESTAMP ) ) AS FirstVisit, 
       MAX( DATE( TIMESTAMP ) ) AS LastVisit
       FROM behaviour
       WHERE MIN( DATE( TIMESTAMP ) ) != MAX( DATE( TIMESTAMP ) )
       GROUP BY hash
```

How can I edit this query so as to not show the rows that FirstVisit equals LastVisit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregate function`can't be used in`where`clause, but can be used in`having`.

Try this:

```
SELECT
     COUNT( id ) AS pages,
     hash,
     MIN( DATE( TIMESTAMP ) ) AS FirstVisit,
     MAX( DATE( TIMESTAMP ) ) AS LastVisit
FROM behaviour 
GROUP BY hash
HAVING MIN( DATE( TIMESTAMP ) ) != MAX( DATE( TIMESTAMP ) )
```